# Data errors from network device at high ambient temperature(60C)

Tags: heat, component-failure, bit-error

[image]I have a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 based network device that I am trying to get working at high ambient temperatures (up to 60C).  When I run TCP packets through the device, I get checksum errors indicating that bits are being corrupted somewhere in the data path.  Besides using the Compute Modules, an FPGA and microcontroller are used as the data processing elements as part of the PCB.

I have reasonably ruled out the Compute Modules as the problem as they have a heat pipe design that keeps them cool enough. And the test outlined below seem to validate this as well.

The data processing components also exist on a separate PCB. I used that separate PCB to test the Compute modules and those components (FPGA and MCU with relevant power converters) at high heat, with one being in the chamber while the other was not.  The only time this failed was when the device was used in the normal configuration.  The external data processing PCB was even able to go up to 90C ambient.  The only difference between these components are the buck converters to deliver power.

Is it reasonable to guess that the buck converters are what are failing and causing fluctuations in voltage to the other components which causes them to process data incorrectly?  Would anyone else have any other possibilities as I am stumped?

Edit for clarity:

The network device's data processing section uses the same design as an already existing PCB/device.  So the FPGA, MCU and all other components, except the buck converters, were taken from that design and integrated into the network device's PCB.

The "normal configuration" is when the network device uses the components that are found on its own PCB.  I have also tested:

1. the network device inside the test chamber with wires coming out connecting to the data processing section on the separate PCB.  This gives no errors which leads me away from suspecting the RPi as this essentially isolates the 2 sections
2. the separate data processing PCB in the test chamber with the network device outside at room temperature.  This device was able to reach 90C ambient, so this tells me that the FPGA and MCU are also not failing.

Comment: Welcome :-) Unfortunately I found the description of the construction to be confusing e.g in para 1 you mention *the* PCB, but in para 3 you then mention a *separate* PCB. Then you mention failures only occur in "normal configuration" - is that everything on one PCB, or split across 2 PCBs, or something else? Adding some photos or diagrams would help clarify things IMHO. Regarding your suspicions about the buck converters, have you looked at their output(s) with a scope, and compared their outputs between the working and failing tests? Can you add those scope traces into the question? Thanks.

Comment: The "Thermals" section of the [CM3 datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/datasheets/rpi_DATA_CM_3p0.pdf) highlights the temperatures of the eMMC and LPDDR2 as being limiting factors: can you measure the temperatures of those?

Comment: @SamGibson I have edited the question, hopefully this clears things up.  Let me know if you are still unsure.  The output of the buck converters was the next thing on my list.  I managed to tack wires to the points of interest and do a quick measurement with a DVM, but did not see anything unusual.  I will definitely try with a scope next, I just wanted to make sure I was on the right track. I am not an EE so this is relatively new to me.

Comment: @AndrewMorton See my edit above, as I think it rules out the CM as the issue here.  The LPDDR2 failing is an interesting thought that I haven't considered.  I don't think I could measure the temperature, but putting a heat sink on it couldn't hurt

Comment: @rt0218 - Thanks for the update. (a) I would still prefer photos / diagrams as I mentioned, to help ensure that my mental model matches the actual physical design. Without that, I can't be *sure*. You indicate that the combined new PCB (RPi CM3 + FPGA + MCU + buck converters) is only different from the CM3 + separate FPGA + MCU design by having the buck regulators - however I would not be surprised if there are additional discrete components (e.g. caps) too, which is again why photos (or schematics) would help. Deep dive into the differences between the two configurations. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] (b) You must view the buck outputs with a scope, not a DVM, to identify many types of possible problem. DVMs can only identify the most "gross" issues. Beware of the earthed "ground leads" on most mains scopes, in case your design is not compatible with using a scope in the normal way e.g. ground lead to the 0V rail (without schematics, readers can't tell if that's going to be a potential problem for you, or not).

Comment: @SamGibson I posted a poorly drawn diagram of the system, one or the other "data processing" section is used, with the internal one being the normal configuration that I want to get working.

Comment: [Cont]   While different passive components are used, I don't really expect that they are what is causing the issue.  Yes, I agree, using the scope is the next thing I will do.  I am not sure if I can provide schematics, so we may have to go based on part names.  Other than the buck converters, would you have any idea of parts that are specifically susceptible to heat?

Comment: Possible that the buck converter can't be cooled at this temperature and doesn't work properly. Same with any other component requiring cooling like processors, transistors switching at high speed etc...